# DataTables move rows between tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm building a simple interface for a sql query result.

I've choose to use DataTables and with it help I've created something like this:

http://live.datatables.net/izavon/18/edit#javascript,html,live

I have problem with moving rows from one table to another, right now I have 2 functions that do their job, but I would like to have one function, because my solution only works in one direction-I can move from one table to another just ones.

```
$(".deleteMe1").on("click", function (event) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
    var addElement = oTable1.fnGetData(row);
    oTable2.fnAddData(addElement);
    // Remove Element from the source table
    var removeElement = oTable1.fnGetPosition(row);
    oTable1.fnDeleteRow(removeElement, null, true);
});

$(".deleteMe2").on("click", function (event) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
    var addElement = oTable2.fnGetData(row);
    oTable1.fnAddData(addElement);
    // Remove Element from the source table
    var removeElement = oTable2.fnGetPosition(row);
    oTable2.fnDeleteRow(removeElement, null, true);
});
```

So my questions is:**How to merge above functions into one.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the rows are changing, bind the delete button to a lower unchanging element with .on, in the case below the click event is bound to $(document) and then focused with the second parameter.

```
$(document).on("click", '.deleteMe', function (event) 
{
    // Get the id of the clicked table for comparison
    var id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');

    // Assign the tables to the table object
    var table = {
        primary : (id === 'example1') ? oTable1 : oTable2,
        secondary : (id !== 'example1') ? oTable1 : oTable2
    };

    // Instead of calling the tables in seperate functions just use the  dynamically
    // assigned table.primary.x() and table.secondary.x()
    var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);

    var addElement = table.primary.fnGetData(row);

    table.secondary.fnAddData(addElement);

    var removeElement = table.secondary.fnGetPosition(row);

    table.primary.fnDeleteRow(removeElement, null, true);

});
```

[Updated Datatables example using above](http://live.datatables.net/uwiseb)

This will work both ways depending on which table the remove button was clicked in. You can modify this to work in one or both directions easily by hardcoding the primary / secondary table variables or making the .on functions second parameter to a class that is only used in one table.

To run updates on the table, add this line to the bottom of the above function:

```
oTable1.fnDraw();
```

This will force the table to re-draw everytime a new line is added or removed, this is useful to you as you can use:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function() {
    console.log('draw callback executed');
 };
```

within your datatable object to specify exactly what should happen. Updating the footer, pull relevant ajax data etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer :) That's answers my first question, but what should I do with show/hide link? Try to remove `fnFooterCallback` this way columns 2-8 hide and 9 is visible, can I modify is somehow? Or do I must use fnDrawCallback? And how to access second row in my footer? BIG BIG THANKS :)

Comment: well `fnFooterCallback` is called when the footer is redrawn on the page. Both have their uses it's just when they're fired is the different. You can't get access to row data within `fnDrawCallback` so in your case keep using the footer callback.

Comment: yes but how to fix my code? When I remove `fnFooterCallback` my columns show/hide correctly, but when I add it suddenly I get weird behaviour-only third columns hides. Open Your example, try to move rows from one table to another, this works grate, then click `hide` link ones and try to move rows, rows don't update correctly. So I think that my show/hide function crashes all :(

Comment: P.S. Sorry for my English, hope my question and comments are understandable :)