# Move (add/delete) tr rows between datatables table and plain DOM table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

There are quite some answers to be found about moving rows between two datatables.
([DataTables move rows between tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384851/datatables-move-rows-between-tables)).
However, doing that between one datatable and one plain DOM table has proven to be quite the struggle.

I have one Datatable:

```
    var colcount = $("#uitschrdiv").children("thead > tr:first").children().length;
    dtable = $("#uitschrdiv").dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
            "sUrl": "/css/datatables/nl.txt"
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [colcount - 1] }
        ],
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "Alles"]],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bStateSave": true,
        "iCookieDuration": 60 * 30 /* 30min */
    });
```

I have one normal DOM table named `#inschrdiv`

each of them has a button in the last `td` to move the row to the other table.
How to switch `tr`'s between the two of them?

before I switched one of the tables to a datatables, this was the jQuery that would move the TR's

```
    $(".uitschrbut").live("click", function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("inactivebtn")) {
            //werkt niet
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("uitschrbut").addClass("inschrbut").val("inschrijven");
            $("#uitschrdiv").append($(this).parent().parent());
            checkInEnUitschrMax();
        }
    });

    $(".inschrbut").live("click", function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("inactivebtn")) {
            //werkt niet
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("uitschrbut").removeClass("inschrbut").val("uitschrijven");
            $("#inschrdiv").append($(this).parent().parent());
            checkInEnUitschrMax();
        }
    });
```

this does not at all work with Datatables.

Answer (score 0):

The solution took me a while before I understood that Datatables can only work with DOM objects on removing/adding and doesn't handle jQuery objects.

This is what I ended up with:

```
    $(".uitschrbut").live("click", function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("inactivebtn")) {
            //werkt niet
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("uitschrbut").addClass("inschrbut").val("inschrijven");
            var jrow = $(this).parents("tr");
            jrow.detach(); //you need to detach this because if the datatable has a filter applied in search, it will stay in this table until the filter fits the data in this row. It would only then be moved to the datatable.
            dtable.fnAddTr(jrow[0]); //used plugin, see below, jrow[0] gets the DOM of jrow
            checkInEnUitschrMax();
        }
    });

    $(".inschrbut").live("click", function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("inactivebtn")) {
            //werkt niet
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("uitschrbut").removeClass("inschrbut").val("uitschrijven");
            var row = $(this).parent().parent()[0]; //the [0] gets the native DOM elem
            $("#inschrdiv tbody").append(row); //append the DOM element to the other table
            dtable.fnDeleteRow(row); //delete this row from the datatable

            checkInEnUitschrMax();
        }
    });
```

You will need the plugin `fnAddTr` which can be found here: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnAddTr

If you want to add more than one row at once you can use this plugin that allows you to apparently add whole DOM tables at once into a datatable: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/31377#Comment_31377